# Using ml5.js in JavaScript how do you return resultP.html?

Tags: javascript, database, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm just a beginner but I have to use this for school. So I used this library for JavaScript called ml5.js which uses machine learning to detect a word you are saying and displays is on screen, only 18 words are in the database. I used this as a starting point but didn't get really far.

When for example you say the word 'left', left show up on screen but when it does I want to console.log 'good fun'. After hours of trying I couldn't figure it out, so I hope someone can help me.

So I want if resultP.html(results[0].label) = 'left' then console.log   'Good fun'

New to this platform but here is my code:

**[HTML]**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  *head*

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.3.1/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  *body*

    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body 
{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
  }

  canvas {

    display: block;

  }
```

**Javascript**

```
console.log ('ml5 version:', ml5.version)

let soundClassifier;
var resultP;

function preload() {
  let options = { probabilityThreshold: 0.94 };
  soundClassifier = ml5.soundClassifier('SpeechCommands18w', options);
  
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  resultP = createP('waiting...');
  resultP.style('font-size','32pt');
  soundClassifier.classify(gotResults);
}

function gotResults(error, results) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('something went wrong');
    console.error(error);
  }
  resultP.html(results[0].label);
  console.log (results[0].label) 
}




function good (){
  if (resultP.html(results[0].label) == 'left') {
    console.log ('good fun')
  } 
    
}
```

So I want if resultP.html(results[0].label) = 'left' then console.log 'Good fun'

I hope someone is able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're really close! Just call your good() function from inside your gotResults() function like this:

```js
console.log ('ml5 version:', ml5.version)

let soundClassifier;
var resultP;

function preload() {
  let options = { probabilityThreshold: 0.94 };
  soundClassifier = ml5.soundClassifier('SpeechCommands18w', options);

}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  resultP = createP('waiting...');
  resultP.style('font-size','32pt');
  soundClassifier.classify(gotResults);
}

function gotResults(error, results) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('something went wrong');
    console.error(error);
  }
  resultP.html(results[0].label);
  console.log (results[0].label);
  good(results[0].label);
}


function good (label){
  if (label) === 'left') {
    console.log ('good fun')
  } 

}
```